# The most stable metal for radioactive environment

Tags: space, radiation

Could you suggest which metal/alloy shows the least activation & better long-term stability for space (LEO, inside Van allen belts, deep space) applications?

Or stability of construction elements isn't an issue comparing to stability of electronics?

Comment: Google for "spacecraft materials". This brings up a lot of sites, I think You will find some of them useful, if only to show better links

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what this question is asking about. Could you give an example of some material that would be "unstable", and the actual process by which it degrades? Are we talking about radiation embrittlement here? "Activation" makes me think neutron activation, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer yet, have to back to goodle.